# Excel VBA:How to use StrComp in a While statement when one string is a text value contained in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

The code returning an error is the first line of the following:

```
    While StrComp(selectedRecipe, dataSheet.Cells(i, 1)) <> 0
             recipeRow = recipeRow + 1
             i = i + 1
    Wend
```

The debug I'm getting has issues with the While statement line itself. This code is contained under an OK Button click event on a userform, with selectedRecipe defined as a public string variable in the main worksheet sub. "i" is defined as an integer in this private sub. Basically the code is to find which row of the sheet holds the string value contained in selectedRecipe after selectedRecipe is selected from a drop-down combo box (selectedRecipe returns correctly and has no issues associated with it). I assume I need to have some sort of "converting" command in front of "dataSheet.Cells(i,1)" to reinforce the cell value as a string, but am not sure. Thanks!

Comment: If `i` is an `Integer` it can overflow. It should be declared as `Long`. `i` also needs to be at least 1 when you enter the loop. This also begs the question why you're using `StrComp` instead of simply `While selectedRecipe <> dataSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value`. Finally, you'll run off the end of the sheet if you don't find `selectedRecipe` in column 1.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure dataSheet is actually set to a valid sheet. 2) as Comintern said, you need to begin at 1 as Excel is 1 based not zero based. 3) You need to make sure you don't overflow the number of rows:

```
 Public Sub CheckRecipe()

    Dim selectedRecipe As String
    Dim i As Long
    selectedRecipe = "Test"
    i = 1

    While StrComp(selectedRecipe, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value) <> 0 _
        And i < ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        i = i + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```